# Spring Batch: OnSkipInWrite prints the log twice ??? How ?

Tags: spring-batch

Im facing a wierd situation while executing the spring batch. I've configured my job step execution to use "skippable-exception-classes" as

```
<step id="prepareFileStep" next="fillRecordsCounterStep">
<tasklet>
   <chunk reader="stagingIdReader" writer="customerIdRecordCompWriter" commit-interval="50" skip-limit="200">
    <streams>
         <stream ref="flatFileRecordWriter" />
    </streams>
    <skippable-exception-classes>
         <include class="java.lang.Exception" /> 
    </skippable-exception-classes>
</chunk>
<listeners>
         <listener ref="prepareFlatFileSkipListener" />
    <listener ref="prepareFlatFileStepListener" />
</listeners>
</tasklet>
```

And my onSkipInWrite() is implemented as:

```
@OnSkipInWrite
public void onSkipInWrite(Object item, Throwable exception) {
    AppLog.warn(AppConstants.CALLER, "Skipping Customer Id:"+ item.getCustomer().getCustomerId()+"\n" + exception.toString());
}
```

I wonder why the log file has printed skipped items twice, thou when I debug it executes only once? Please suggest me the fix friends...

Answer (score 1):

Most likely due to spring batch chunk has been rolled back and retried again as one chunk item at a time (instead of the whole chunk size):

[Spring Batch: skipping during item write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729260/spring-batch-skipping-during-item-write/6730807#6730807)