# Spring batch Writer, Processor called twice on skip?

Tags: spring-batch

I have a very basic question regarding skip. i am using the spring-batch-simple-cli project provided by spring samples, and trying to understand the skip behaviour. this has a very basic example reader that reads from an array of strings ( i have modifed it to read from a list of 10 strings starting from Hellowworld 1 to Hellowworld 10) and a basic writer that logs to console. writer throws java.lang.Exception on each write.
i have added a skip limit of 4 to job configuration. once it reached Hellowworld 5, the job stops as expected.
But whenever writer throws exception, the writer is called back immediately with the same item. My question why is writer called twice? i am expecting this item to be just skipped? is there something i am missing.

```
<job id="job1" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" incrementer="jobParametersIncrementer">
    <step id="step1" parent="simpleStep">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="reader" writer="writer" skip-limit="4" >
                <skippable-exception-classes>
                    <include class="java.lang.Exception" />
                </skippable-exception-classes>
            </chunk>
        </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely caused by the default functionality, where spring batch rollbacks the chunk and retries each chunk item (in this case there is only one item) again.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6730807/1627688

Comment: My bad, I did not realize this.

Comment: This is actually making my writer to write twice same record. An idea to prevent that?